# Prevent a webpage from navigating away

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

i am using inertia Link component in my vuejs. i want to prevent webpage from navigating away to another page. how can I implement in my laravel and vuejs project.

i am trying

```
mounted() {
        router.on('before', (event) => {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to navigate away?')
        })
},
```

when I visit another page to another page its pop up all pages